# Adding flagging to the review of low-quality posts

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flagging, review

In the review page for low-quality posts,

When reviewing answers (at least) it is sometimes the case that the answer is in fact a comment by a low-reputation user. While voting for deletion is fine, and even leaving a comment is fine, I think we should be allowed to flag this for the moderators to *convert* the answer to a comment.

Sometimes it is useless, e.g. when the answer is just another question. In such case there is nothing to do except leaving a comment and [voting for] deleting. But sometimes it's reasonable to flag the answer.

Comment: I was about to write a similar question (except bringing to attention the fact that a moderator might need to review offensive posts). Given this was so highly upvoted, is there a reason it seems to have gotten no attention in the way of comments?

Comment: Beats me... :-)

Comment: I have up voted, but there is of course a way to flag such posts in the current scheme, just not as part of the review queue itself.  I can think of a reason moderators might not want to add flags into the scope of the review queue itself.

Answer (score 2):

What is the status of this? Two years later and this functionality *still* hasn't been implemented?

Not-an-answer answers (those that should be comments, or those that should be edits) in the low-quality and first-post queues are a very common occurence.

Comment: Maybe if I flag this, and it appears on the review queue, that review queue will have the ability to flag the post (because it makes sense to have it as a comment!), although I get it, you wanted to bump it up. So it's fine. ;-)

Comment: Probable reason this hasn't been implemented: this type of answer-but-actually-a-comment is often done by low rep users, those who can't comment yet. This would be a way for them to bypass this restriction: they purposefully make their comment into an answer, knowing that it will be converted anyway. (Not saying I agree or disagree, just that this is probably a factor in why it hasn't been implemented)

Comment: Right, but turning it into a comment requires a moderator's attention (through flags). So when I see this type of answer, I have to leave the review queue by opening a new window, flag the post, go back to the review queue, and decide what to do with the queue item ("looks good" usually). The cleaner workflow would be a "flag" button along with "edit" etc straight in the queue.

Comment: I vote to delete, leaving a templated comment about how the answer should be a comment. If the author cares, they can repost as a comment. (They have access to deleted their posts.) If not, everybody moves on. The cases when this content is truly valuable enough to get out of the queue and write a custom flag message are very rare.